# Signed .CAB results in "Unknown publisher" on windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, digital-certificate, authenticode

I have purchased a certificate from http://www.ksoftware.net/ which I use to sign a .CAB file used for installation of our software on windows mobile 6.5 devices. However, even after signing the .CAB, when attempting to install the application on the device (via the CAB) the device alerts "Unknown publisher".  These CAB files are downloaded from a webservice and are supposed to be installed automatically using wceload and its silent install options, but this fails since the CAB is not recognized as signed (once I have manually installed a particular CAB file, wceload will succeed for that CAB in the future).

Initially I only had the certificate set in the visual studio 2008 deployment properties, and the applications signing properties.  I also tried using signtool.exe, and thereafter cabsigntool.exe to sign all the other files in the CAB too. None of these methods work.  When checking the CAB's properties in Windows 7, the file does have a security certificate attached, but any attempt to install on the device gives the annoying "unknown publisher" popup box.

Is there anything I am missing? What could be causing the devices to still see the CAB files as unsigned?  The signing does not seem to work with plain exe's either.

Please note I do know the security settings can be changed in order for the prompt not to come up, but I am interested in solving the security certificate problem.

Comment: For future reference: Comodo did some research and their certificate is not valid on Windows mobile 6.5, only Verisign certificates can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the root certificate of the sign is not know on the device:

[image]

Did you verify that the certs are WindowsMobile compatible?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is a comodo certificate, which is apparently covered by the certificate 'Addtrust external CA root', which is present on the device.  I have contacted comodo and awaiting a reply.